# Double clicks from (document) instead of one to close select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a  dropdown list, and I want, if click on the select tag to add the class 'active' to the span tag and remove it if click again. But I also want that if I click on the document page it should remove the class 'active' if it added to the span tag. It work.. but I should double click from the document instead of one to remove the active class.. 
I'm sure that there are a shorter and better code to do this trick but anyway it work a little like that :) 
Any help would be appreciated

Here the basic html:

```
<select class="qty">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
</select>
<span class="arrow"></span>
```

Jquery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

 var arrow = $('.arrow');

 $(".qty").on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if(arrow.hasClass('active')) {
     arrow.removeClass('active');
  } 
  else {
     arrow.addClass('active'); 
  }
 });

 $(document).on('click', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   if(arrow.hasClass('active')) {
     arrow.removeClass('active');
   }
   else { 
     return false;
   }
 });
});
```

## **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv3166q7/)**

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue with the "double-click" is that when you select an option in the dropdown, it remains focused (browser behaviour). This means you need to click twice, not necessarily double click. First you need to click elsewhere to remove focus from it, and only then the body element can listen to your click.

Not sure what you are trying to do, maybe the  is not your best option. You could consider making your own dropdown with a *DIV* or *UL LI* elements. However, if you do want to patch the browser behaviour, you could force it to blur (unfocus). You would need to change the trigger to *change* instead of a *click*, otherwise it would blur it before you make your selection.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

 var arrow = $('.arrow');

 $(".qty").on("change", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  arrow.toggleClass("active");
  $(this).blur();
 });

 $(document).on('click', function(e) {
   arrow.removeClass('active');
 });
});
```

Also, note that you can use *.toggleClass* instead of you if statements and in your case you wouldn't need to check if the *.active* class is already there, you can simply remove it.

Here's an updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lv3166q7/1/)

Comment: Thanks you for your help, but when I click on the select tab in your fiddle, it doesnt add the class 'active' is it normal ?

I tried to change **.on("change")** to **.on("click")**, like that it work but the dropdown slideup directly after I click on the select tag.

Comment: With .on("change"), the event is only trigger when an option is different from the selected one to a different one (e.g. if "1" was selected and then you select "2"). Otherwise it seems to be working fine on Chrome / Mac OS, but may be browser-dependent. on("click") removes the focus on the element to prevent the need to double click you mentioned. Depending on what you're doing a custom HTML/CSS dropdown may be a better option than the native <select> element. Hope this helps!